# My code generates a random integer output and I do not know why

Tags: c, unix, cygwin, nano

I am having difficulties with the output of a program for an assignment and I cannot figure out what is causing my problem. The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int find_minimum(int *a, int n)
{  
    int *last=(a + n);
    int minimum = *a;
    while(a!=last){
        if(*a < minimum)
        minimum=*a;        
        a++;
    }
    
   return minimum;
}

int main()
{
    int N;
    printf("Enter number of parts (N): ");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    
    int K;
    printf("Enter number of part types (K): ");
    scanf("%d",&K);
    
    int a[K];
    
    printf("Enter Part list:\n");
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        int part;
        scanf("%d",&part);
        
        a[part-1]+=1;
    }
    
    printf("The factory can build %d computer(s)",find_minimum(a,K));
    
    return 0;
}
```

This program is supposed to take input for the amount of parts and how many types of parts there are, and then calculate how many possible combinations of computers can be made out of the parts entered. The example input I was given looks like:

```
Enter the number of parts (N): 10

Enter the number of types of parts (K): 2

Enter part list:

1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2

The factory can build 5 computer(s)
```

Upon entering these numbers into the program, I get a randomly generated integer, which is not the intended result. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `a` has only 2 elements. But you're trying to enter 10 parts into it, so you're writing outside the array boundary.

Comment: You seem to have mixed up when to use `N` versus `K`. Try using better variable names.

Comment: You array `a` is not initialized — and contains indeterminate (quasi-random) values.  It is not reliably all zeros.

Answer (score 3):

You declared your array but you did not initialize it. It means that every slot of your array does not have a 0 inside but can have a random value in it.

So doing a[part-1] += 1 add 1 to a random value (note that if part is 0 or > to k you are out of bound). You need to initialize every "slot" to 0.

try to compile and execute this to understand:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
}
```